# Incomplete backup with mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I need to backup sql db around 39GB.
When I'm doing backup without `single-transaction` option - everything is ok, I got full dump of my DB.
But when I try to add `single-transaction` option, I got incomplete dump, last 20 tables always missing.
They all got `InnoDB` engine.
I even try to increase `mac_packet_size` to 512M but it did not help.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Mysql version is:

`mysql  Ver 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`

I notice this error during backup:

`Table definition has changed, please retry transaction when dumping table`

Comment: Are you backing up from a slave/replica database? If so, simply stop replication for the duration of the backup (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting "Table definition has changed, please retry transaction"

Try using `--order-by-size` option which was [motivated by this error](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/2054).

Ref: [mariadb-dump kb page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-dumpmysqldump/).

Comment: Got error, no such option.

Comment: Ah, using MySQL and not MariaDB.